# how to query using postgres json field where a key is not set?

Tags: json, postgresql

I can select records that match a certain json value like `where properties->>'foo' = 'bar'`, but what if the key 'foo' has not yet been set?  I've tried `where properties->>'foo' IS NULL` but I get an error

```
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit   type casts.
: SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants"  WHERE (properties->>'foo' IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an operator precedence issue. `IS NULL` binds more tightly than `->>`, so your code is being read as `properties ->> ('foo' IS NULL)`. Add parentheses - `(properties ->> 'foo') IS NULL`.

```
regress=> SELECT '{"a":1}' ->> 'a';
 ?column? 
----------
 1
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT '{"a":1}' ->> 'b';
 ?column? 
----------

(1 row)

regress=> SELECT '{"a":1}' ->> 'b' IS NULL;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown ->> boolean
LINE 1: SELECT '{"a":1}' ->> 'b' IS NULL;
                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
regress=> SELECT ('{"a":1}' ->> 'b') IS NULL;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```